# Regex: How to match any letters up until a number And Matching a Dash

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match sequences of strings that follow certain rules:

- rlg3-22, rlas1-4
- pz
- xx-0
- r1-6

For example, in the first row, I want to match the string up until the "-" character, so that I can perform the following function of expanding the string into (rlg3, rlg4, ..., rlg22).

In the second row, I would leave it as is.

In the third row, I would also leave it as is because there was no number first.

Thank you!

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Also please explain better; it's not clear what you even want

Answer (score 0):

```
d = 'rlg3-22'

import re
ops = re.findall(r"\d+",d)         # r"\d+" searches for digits of variables length
prefix = re.findall(r"\D+", d)[0]  # r"\D+" complement set of "\d+"
```

build the list and add the prefix to the string cast of the integer

```
 [prefix + str(i) for i in list(range(int(ops[0]), int(ops[1]),1))]

['rgl3',
 'rgl4',
 'rgl5',
 'rgl6',
 'rgl7',
 'rgl8',
 'rgl9',
 'rgl10',
 'rgl11',
 'rgl12',
 'rgl13',
 'rgl14',
 'rgl15',
 'rgl16',
 'rgl17',
 'rgl18',
 'rgl19',
 'rgl20',
 'rgl21']
```